# Rewriting a Linq query to use if / else and ditch the var

Tags: c#, .net

I've recently started playing with Linq (cue groans), and am trying to get the following to compile. Now, the whereclause part uses DynamicLinq, which works fine; it's the var placeholder variable that the compiler wants a real class for; unfortunately, I am using what I believe is an anonymous class, and am not sure how to take it from here. Any suggestions?

```
var query;
if(whereclause != string.Empty) 
{
    query = Directory.GetFiles(LRSettings.Default.OperatingDirectory, LRSettings.Default.FileExtension,
    SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsQueryable()
        .Select(Filename => new { Filename, new FileInfo(Filename)
        .LastWriteTime, new FileInfo(Filename).Extension, new FileInfo(Filename).Length })
        .Where(whereclause);
}
else 
{
    query = Directory.GetFiles(LRSettings.Default.OperatingDirectory,
                               LRSettings.Default.FileExtension,
                               SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .AsQueryable()
        .Select(Filename => new { Filename, new FileInfo(Filename).LastWriteTime, new FileInfo(Filename).Extension, new FileInfo(Filename).Length });
}
```

Comment: @JasonWatkins Must work in a Java shop :D

Comment: Nonsense, C# all the way. Linq has just been a painful experience these past two weeks...

Comment: The `Where(whereclause)` will not work, if `whereclause` is a string. The `.Where()` needs a `Func<T>` or even `Expression<Funct<T>>` - that's for another question.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am using DynamicLinq, so the whereclause can accept a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems like the only difference in your query is whether or not to include a `WHERE` clause, you should just be able to do this:

```
var query = Directory.GetFiles(LRSettings.Default.OperatingDirectory, LRSettings.Default.FileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .AsQueryable()
        .Select(Filename => new { Filename, new FileInfo(Filename).LastWriteTime, new FileInfo(Filename).Extension, new FileInfo(Filename).Length });

if(whereclause != string.Empty) 
{
    query = query.Where(whereclause);
}
```

Since you're using an `IEnumerable`, I don't think you have to worry about pulling too much data without the `Where()` clause, since it doesn't get enumerated until you access `query` in some fashion (like binding to a form or whatnot).

Answer (score 1):

Two immediate options are to use [`?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) or to extract the common/starting query.

For the former:

```
bool expr = SomeTrueOrFalseValue();
var l = new [] { 1,2,3 };
// both "true" and "false" branches unify an IEnumerable<int>
var q = expr
  ? l
  : l.Where(x => x > 1);
// q typed as IEnumerable<int>
```

For the latter:

```
var q = l.AsEnumerable();
// q is typed as IEnumerable<int>
if (!expr) {
    q = q.Where(x => x > 1);
}
// q is still typed as IEnumerable<int> - can't be changed after var
```

An assignment *must* be included in a [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) declaration so the variable's type can be determined.

But without var:

```
IEnumerable<int> q; // not practical/possible for complex types
if (expr) {
   q = l;
} else {
   q = l.Where(x => x > 1);
}
```